# Invalid valid error while inserting to postgress db using node and sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js

I am using node sequelize library to insert data in postgress db

this is my user model  in Users.ts file

```
export class User extends Sequelize.Model {
  public id!: number;
  public name: string;
  public email: string;
  public googleId: string;

  public password: string;
  // public preferredName!: string | null; // for nullable fields

  // timestamps!
  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;

  async comparePassword(candidatePassword: string, callback: Function) {
    try {
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password);
      callback(undefined, isMatch);
    } catch (err) {
      callback(err);
    }
  }
}

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(128),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    googleId: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(128),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(300),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    token: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(300),
      allowNull: true,
    },
  },
  {

    tableName: 'users',
    sequelize: sequelize, // this bit is important
  }
);
```

When i try to create a new record in the db using

```
await User.create({name, email, password, address});
```

it always return me error with invalid value with whatever input i give

> Error: Invalid value { name: 'd' }  at Object.escape
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sql-string.js:65:11)
>   at PostgresQueryGenerator.escape
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:964:22)
>   at PostgresQueryGenerator._whereParseSingleValueObject
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2431:41)
>   at PostgresQueryGenerator.whereItemQuery
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2149:19)
>   at Utils.getComplexKeys.map.prop
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2206:21)
>   at Array.map () at PostgresQueryGenerator._whereBind
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2204:43)
>   at PostgresQueryGenerator.whereItemQuery
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2139:19)
>   at Utils.getComplexKeys.forEach.prop
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2048:25)
>   at Array.forEach () at
>   PostgresQueryGenerator.whereItemsQuery
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2046:35)
>   at PostgresQueryGenerator.getWhereConditions
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2458:19)
>   at PostgresQueryGenerator.selectQuery
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1279:28)
>   at QueryInterface.select
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:1120:27)
>   at Promise.try.then.then.then
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1748:34)
>   at tryCatcher
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>   at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
>   at Promise._settlePromise
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
>   at Promise._settlePromise0
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
>   at Promise._settlePromises
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:694:18)
>   at _drainQueueStep
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
>   at _drainQueue
>   (/Users/eali/learn/akasa-server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)

Comment: Are you just calling it like this?
User.create({name, email, password, address});
You need to add values to your object keys in the create method...
{name: 'john wayne', email: 'lol@example.com', password: '1234', address: 'Someplace 1'}

Comment: i am using es6 syntax

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you forgot to add values to your property keys:

```js
await User.create({name, email, password, address});
```

should be:

```js
await User.create({name: 'john wayne', email: 'lol@example.com', password: '1234', address: 'Someplace 1'});
```